# Is there a way to export default 2 constants?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

*Note: I am a beginner learning React Native.* I have two js files (Inputs.js and Styles.js) and I am trying to put them both in a `const` in my main js file (App.js) but I can only `export default` one of them. Is there a way I can export both of them or should I rearrange my code in another way?

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Home1 = () => {
   return (
      <Style/>
   )
}
const Home2 = () =>{
   return (
      <Inputs />
   )
}

export default Home1; //I am unable to export both Home1 and Home2 here
```

**Style.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const Style = () => {
    return ( <View style = {styles.container}>
         <Text style = {styles.text}>
            <Text style = {styles.capitalLetter}>
               Title Here
            </Text>
            <Text>
                <Text style = {styles.textInput}> {"\n"} {"\n"}{"\n"}Location: </Text>
            </Text>
            <Text>
                <Text style = {styles.textInput}> {"\n"} {"\n"}Time:</Text>
            </Text>
            <Text>
                <Text style = {styles.textInput}> {"\n"} {"\n"}Time: </Text>
            </Text>
         </Text>
      </View>
   )
}

export default Style

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   container: {
      //alignItems: 'center',
      marginTop: 50,
   },

   text: {
      color: '#41cdf4',
   },

   capitalLetter: {
      color: 'red',
      fontSize: 20
   },

   textInput: {
      padding: 22,
      //fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'black'
   },


   textShadow: {
      textShadowColor: 'red',
      textShadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
      textShadowRadius : 5
   }
})
```

**Inputs.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

class Inputs extends Component {

   state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
   }

   handleEmail = (text) => {
      this.setState({ email: text })
   }

   handlePassword = (text) => {
      this.setState({ password: text })
   }

   login = (email, pass) => {
      alert('email: ' + email + ' password: ' + pass)
   }

   render(){
      return (
         <View style = {styles.container}>
            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Email"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {this.handleEmail}/>

            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Password"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {this.handlePassword}/>

            <TouchableOpacity
               style = {styles.submitButton}
               onPress = { () => this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
               <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}>
                  Submit
               </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      )
   }
}

export default Inputs

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      paddingTop: 200
   },

   input: {
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
      borderColor: '#7a42f4',
      borderWidth: 1
   },

   submitButton: {
      backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
      padding: 10,
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
   },

   submitButtonText:{
      color: 'white'
   }
})
```

****UPDATED CODE BELOW for the error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`:*****

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

module.exports = { 
  Home1() {
    return (
      <Style/>
    );
  }, 
  Home2() {
    return (
      <Inputs/>
    );
  } 
};
```

**Style.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Inputs } from "./App.js"
import Home1, {Home2} from './App.js'

const Style = () => {
    return ( <View style = {styles.container}>
         <Text style = {styles.text}>
            <Text style = {styles.capitalLetter}>
               Title Here
            </Text>
            <Text>
                <Text style = {styles.textInput}> {"\n"} {"\n"}{"\n"}Your address or location (eg, Nashville, TN): </Text>
            </Text>
            <Text>
                <Text style = {styles.textInput}> {"\n"} {"\n"}Contact 2:</Text>
            </Text>
            <Text>
                <Text style = {styles.textInput}> {"\n"} {"\n"}Contact 3: </Text>
            </Text>
         </Text>
      </View>
   )
}

export default Style

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   container: {
      //alignItems: 'center',
      marginTop: 50,
   },

   text: {
      color: '#41cdf4',
   },

   capitalLetter: {
      color: 'red',
      fontSize: 20
   },

   textInput: {
      padding: 22,
      //fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'black'
   },


   textShadow: {
      textShadowColor: 'red',
      textShadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
      textShadowRadius : 5
   }
})
```

**Inputs.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
//import { Style } from "./App.js"
import Home1, {Home2} from './App.js'

class Inputs extends Component {

   state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
   }

   handleEmail = (text) => {
      this.setState({ Location: text })
   }

   handlePassword = (text) => {
      this.setState({ Time: text })
   }

   login = (email, time1) => {
      alert('Location: ' + email  + ' Time: ' + time1)
   }

   render(){
      return (
         <View style = {styles.container}>
            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Location"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {this.handleEmail}/>

            <TextInput style = {styles.input}
               underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
               placeholder = "Time"
               placeholderTextColor = "#9a73ef"
               autoCapitalize = "none"
               onChangeText = {this.handlePassword}/>

            <TouchableOpacity
               style = {styles.submitButton}
               onPress = { () => this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
               <Text style = {styles.submitButtonText}>
                  Submit
               </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      )
   }
}

export default Inputs

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
      paddingTop: 200
   },

   input: {
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
      borderColor: '#7a42f4',
      borderWidth: 1
   },

   submitButton: {
      backgroundColor: '#7a42f4',
      padding: 10,
      margin: 15,
      height: 40,
   },

   submitButtonText:{
      color: 'white'
   }
})
```

Comment: Why don't you just export both, but without `default` ? then you could import then like this : `import { Style, Inputs } from './constant';`

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp So are you saying I should make a js file called constant and then somehow combine both the Style and Inputs files?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. Take a look at @Tomasz Bubala answer, it should be what you need

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp I have reviewed the answer by @Tomasz Bubała but I received an error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` I tried asking the person who wrote the answer, but that person is currently offline.

Comment: That means that react has nothing to render. Can you add the file where you import App.js  and update the code in the question?

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp I just added the updated code

Comment: Can you add the file where you call App.js ?

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp It is there. It is right below the text that says "UPDATED BELOW"

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp Maybe I misunderstand your question. What do you mean the file where I call App.js? I call App.js at the top of every js file.

Comment: whats the point in importing them into app.js if you're just going to export them? where are you using these?

Comment: @Matt Aft You are right, I took them out of my code and I still get the same error.

Comment: @user1049876 now, how and where are you importing these? can you post that code?

Comment: @MattAft I don't understand your question. What importing are you referring to? I posted all of the code that I am using for this application.

Comment: i think you deleted the wrong thing, if you delete the module.exports part does the error go away?

Comment: @MattAft If I go back to what I originally had before the edited version, there were no errors. When I comment out that code and have nothing in the App.js file besides the 2 lines of imports, I get that error.

Comment: I think that your error is that you do not register your main component. Take a look at this [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#hello-world). You will see that you need a component that wrap your app and you need to register this component (the last line of code in the example)

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp You mean the AppRegistry line?

Comment: @user1049876 Yes

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp I still receive the same error. I added the line `AppRegistry.registerComponent('SimpleVersion', () => App);` to the end of the App.js file

Comment: Have you created a component called `App` and is your app name `SimpleVersion` ?

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp I don't have any components in App,js so that's why I chose `App`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149655/discussion-between-antoine-grandchamp-and-user1049876).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a component like the code that is shown below, which works, and shows both the Style.js and the Inputs.js files in the app:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Style from './Style.js';
import Inputs from './Inputs.js';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <View> 
        <Style/> // here, both the Style and Inputs files can be used
        <Inputs/> 
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `module.exports` in this case to export an object with two methods. Usage:

```
export function Home1() {
  return (
    <Style/>
  );
};
export function Home2() {
  return (
    <Inputs/>
  );
};
```

This is part of your file called App.js, so in order to import it in another file you need to:

```
import { Home1, Home2 } from "./App.js"
```

In this case you are using **named export**. In order to import it properly you explicitly need to use `import { Home1, Home2 }` with Home1 and Home2 being corresponding names of exported functions.

Comment: I got an error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` Maybe I got this error because I put the wrong information inside of each of the two methods. I put the same thing as I had had before with return and <Style/> or <Inputs/>

Comment: Even with the edits you included into the answer, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You can have just one default export and as many exports as you need:

```
const Home1 = () => { 
  return <Style/>
} 

export const Home2 = () => { 
  return <Inputs />
} 

export default Home1;
```

And then import it like this:

```
import Home1, {Home2} from './App'
```

Comment: I am only getting the Style.js file to show up in my app. I used the import method you have in the Style.js and Inputs.js files and I put in the  first set of code you gave in the App.js file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can replace your component that is not showing with something like one header or paragraph to see if it renders well first. Then after it appears you can put your code back and investigate further ;)

Comment: Why you do this in App.js instead of just <Style /> <Inputs />

Answer (score 2):

You can export const, but only one default const.

```
import React from 'react';

export const myCon1 = (
  // your code goes here
 );

export const myCon2 = (
  // your code goes here
 );
```

in Other side you can import

```
import { myCon1 , myCon2} from '/path_to_file';
```